# Finding duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

Table is as below:

```
Request#  type  status
123         R     partially complete 
123         S     complete
345         S     partially complete
345         S     complete
```

R means a short request, S means a long request. Every request type turns to S when status is "complete". I need to find all "R" type of requests which have been completed

```
select * 
from table 
where type ='R' and status='partially complete' OR 
      type ='s' and status='complete'
```

Expected result

```
Request#  type  
123         R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generalization of Barbaros's solution:

```
select Request#
from "table" 
group by Request#
having sum(case when status = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when type = 'R' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: `Barbaros` in the genitive does not take an apostrophe plus `s`.  So, it should read: `This is a generalization of Barbaros' solution` :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Do you know if the final "s" is pronounced as an "s"?

Comment: It is pronounced phoentically as `Barbarosis`, but we just tag an apostrophe _after_ the final `s`.  I don't have an explanation for this, but I can say that `'s` is a remnant of the genitive case, from middle English.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want this

```
select Request#, min(type) as type
  from "table" 
 group by Request#
 having min(status)='complete'
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach uses aggregation:

```
SELECT
    request
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    request
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'R' AND status = 'partially complete' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'S' AND status = 'complete' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

We might also be able to phrase this using a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.request
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.request = t2.request AND
       t2.type = 'S' AND t2.status = 'complete'
WHERE
    t1.type = 'R' AND
    t1.status = 'partially complete';
```